# Exception when connect to the Oracle Weblogic Cloud 12c server in the OEPE

Tags: weblogic

get the error message when connect to the weblogic cloud 12c from the OEPE Photon, when hit the test connection button, receive error message:
Connection failed
Failed to initialize JNDI context, tried 2 time or times totally, the interval of each time is 0ms.
t3://168.138.9.226:7001: Destination 168.138.9.226, 7001 unreachable.; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect; No available router to destination.; nested exception is:
java.rmi.ConnectException: No available router to destination.

able to connect to the weblogic instance admin console from the browser: https://168.138.9.226:7002/console

JDK 1.8_211

OEPE Photon downloaded from OTN
weblogic instance created from the OCI Stack

Comment: t3 is a binary protocol which is not allowed by default by security components like firewalls. You may also check that port 7001 is opened in your target machine (168....)

Comment: Both of the port 7001 and 7002 and open and the console of the instance is able to be accessed  from the browser, but not from the Eclipse.

Comment: so my problem i am able to access the instance console via the browser but not from the OEPE.

Comment: Any firewall between OOPE and your server instance ?

Comment: I am using a fresh new installed OEPE which download from OTN , unzip and run, no change made to the OEPE settings.

Comment: has anyone tried this before, jdk1.8_211 and OEPE photon with the cloud based weblogic 12.1.4 version?

Comment: the setting works for the local intsalled weblogic server, but just can not connect to the cloud-based weblogic server.

Comment: there is no firewall bt my local and cloud

Comment: can you access the console through the non-secured port (7001) ?

Comment: I can use  both of 7001 and 7002 to access to the cloud weblogic  instance console in the browser, but just can not make connect in the OEPE using the 7001 and 7002